# Using Range and not getting the correct data in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have several hundred files with dates in the names.  I need to pull the date out of the name and put it in the first column of each file on each row in the file.  Example - datarequested20140209.csv

I have already pulled the date from the name and rearranged it - it was backwards for what was requested.  I can add the column and set the first cell - the header - correctly.  If there are more than 2 rows (Header plus 1) then it works fine and puts the date in the cell.

But, if there is only the header row and a single row, it repeats the header in the second row.  I must be missing something.  Any suggestions?

Here is my code so far:

```
    'Writing to the file
Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs
'Getting modified date
Dim FSO, outFQN

Dim sfile, strFolder, strSub1
Dim sYear, sMonth, sDay, sName, sDate
Dim nPos, nPos2

strFolder = "C:\test1"


set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'set objOutput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFolder & "\" & strOutput, 8, true)
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

for each objFile in objFolder.Files
        sfile = objFile.Name
        'Parse and fix date
        nPos = InStr(sfile,"2014")
        nPos2 = "8"
        'msgbox(nPOS)
        sName=MID(sfile, nPos,nPos2)
        'msgbox(sName)
        sYear=MID(sName, 1, 4)
        sMonth=MID(sName, 5, 2)
        sDay=MID(sName, 7, 2)
        sDate = sMonth & "-" & sDay & "-" & sYear
        'sYear = MID(nPO
        'msgbox(sDate)
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objXLApp.Visible = False
    Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\test1\"& sfile)
    ' Working with Sheet1
    Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Sheets(1)
        With objXLWs
            '.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "123"
            .Columns("A:A").Insert xlToRight
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date_Modified"
            .Cells(2, 1).Value = sDate
    set Range = objXLWs.Range("A2:A"&objXLWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count) 
        Range.FillDown
        End With
    ' Save
    StrSub1 = "C:\test1\sub1\"
    objXLWb.SaveAs  StrSub1 & sfile
    objXLWb.Close (False)
    ' File Formats
    '51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2010, xlsx)
    '52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2010, xlsm)
    '50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2010 with or without macro's, xlsb)
    '56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2010, xls)
    Set objXLWs = Nothing
    Set objXLWb = Nothing
    objXLApp.Quit
    Set objXLApp = Nothing
next
```

Thank!

Comment: Is your actual code [not] indented that way?

Comment: Oh, and is it VB.NET, VBA, or VBScript? Can't be all of 'em...

Comment: Sorry - VBscript.  And, it is indented, just was in a rush to post.  Again, Sorry. Will try to fix.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a few more minutes of frustration I came up with this as a fix:

```
set Range = objXLWs.Range("A2:A"&objXLWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count) 
        if objXLWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count = "2" then
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = sDate
        Else
        Range.FillDown
        End if
        End With
```

Added an if statement to ignore the filldown if there was only the 2 rows.  Problem solved!